# Has anyone adapted Otto's Irresistible Dance to the 4e rules?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

It's one of my favorite spells. Are there any official (or formal attempts at) adaptations of it to the 4e rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the level 19 Bard Attack called Irresistible Dance, but its not nearly as fun as 3rd edition because everything is boiled down to statuses and conditions. All you get is the flavor text.

> **Irresistible Dance**
>   An eerie piping fills an area, forcing the creatures there into an idiot dance that sends them careening around at your command.

It's an area burst 1 within 10 squares that does damage, slides, and makes the targets grant combat advantage (save ends).

Comment: Dislike. Also, can't believe I missed that. I'm going to have to roll my own.